# Is it possible to create a composite module out of two of the same modules?

Tags: spring-xd

Using Spring XD 1.3.1 I want to create a composite module that contains more than one instance of a given module. Is this possible?

I tried this simple example:

```
xd:>module compose --name yell --definition "upper: transform --expression=payload.toUpperCase() | exclaim: transform --expression=payload+'!'"
xd:>stream create --name yelling --definition "http | yell | log" --deploy
xd:>http post --data hello
```

and the result printed to the log is:

> 2016-04-13T13:44:33-0700 1.3.1.RELEASE INFO pool-8-thread-1 sink.yelling - HELLO

It seems to have ignored the second `transform` module in the composite. Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is most likely a bug with no known workaround (other than don't make composite modules that consist of duplicated module types).

It is reported here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3650 as

> Unable to compose XD module with several transform processors